# Can the UA Diplomat feat be used to charm multiple targets simultaneously?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, unearthed-arcana, social-combat

Among other benefits, the Diplomat feat from [Unearthed Arcana: Feats for Skills](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-SkillFeats.pdf) allows you to make a contested Persuasion check to charm a creature:

> If you spend 1 minute talking to someone who can understand what you say [...] If your check succeeds, the target is charmed by you as long  as it remains within 60 feet of you and for 1 minute thereafter.

How should this take effect if I am talking to a group of individuals? Can I charm several creatures at once, or only one target at a time?

It feels like it might be the DM's call, but I was curious whether there is any official ruling on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rest of the feat uses singular language. "Someone" is also a singular pronoun. "The target" is singular. Everything here is pointing to a singular target.

Comment: Should be noted that the skill check is a forced one by the player, so long as you take another minute to meet the requisite you can repeat this. However excessive use may have the GM give you disadvantage or target advantage or even both. The feat does not apply magic but the character's natural charismatic ability so, there no reason it can't be attempted multiple times. This is of course assuming the target doesn't start attacking or just simply ignoring you.